# Prove an interior point of $B=\{(x_1,x_2), x_1> 0, x_2> 0\}$ is in the set $A$

Tags: calculus, general-topology

I want to prove that an interior point of $B=\{(x_1,x_2), x_1> 0, x_2> 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is in the set

$A=\{(x_1,x_2), x_1\ge 0, x_2\ge 0\}\subset \mathbb{R}$

For this I've picked a generic point from the set $B$ and imagined an open disk arount it: $D((x_1,x_2),R)$

where $R$ is the radius of the open disk.

I need to prove that every point of this open disk is in $B$, so I've imagined a point $y=(y_1,y_2)$ and I'm trying to prove that 
$$|y-x|<R$$
I guess.

I need help for this, and I'd like someone to help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You want to *pick* an $R$ for each $x$ such that the disk centered at $x$ of radius $R$ is inside $B$. (Any arbitrary $R$ *will not work* - you *have* to pick it.) To figure out what your $R$ must be, consider how close your point $x$ is to each axis.

Comment: I've figured that $R$ must be $min(x_1,x_2)$ but I can't go any further

Comment: Excellent! You know that your disk is actually going to live inside of an open square with side lengths $2R$ centered at $x$. (Draw it if you can't tell!) What can you say about this square?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to observe that $B$ is open and contained in $A$. Hence $\operatorname{Int}(B)\subset B\subset A$.